# Does 越来越多的中国人步入二次购车的行列 talk about second cars or second-hand cars?

Tags: meaning

I'm pretty sure this sentence is referring to '2 car families', but I'd like to check. How should I interpret ‘二次购车’ here？

Maybe they are talking about second hand cars, or families that have previously bought a car and are replacing it???

> 越来越多的中国人步入二次购车的行列，市场细分化程度越来越高。

（As）More and more Chinese people are joining the ranks of the 2 car families, the market is becoming more and more subdivided.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. But I don't see the logic between "越来越多的中国人步入二次购车的行列" and "市场细分化程度越来越高".

Comment: You might need to take up the logic aspect with FLTRP in 北京！

Answer (score 3):

In fact, ‘二次购车’ might not refer to '2 car families', it would be 'previously bought a car and are replacing it' as you said in most cases, but I'm sure that it is not 'second hand cars', since 'second hand cars' is translated as '二手车'.

In my opinion, this sentence may translate as 'More and more Chinese people are buying cars for the second time , the market is becoming more and more subdivided.'

Comment: Thanks, just for your information, you should write '2 car families', the logic behind that escapes me, but it is so. Like saying 'a 2 foot ruler', although the ruler is 2 feet long!

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not second hand car, since that would be translated as '二手车'.

You can simply interpret it with 'buying a second car'.

It doesn't have to be replacing their old cars either. Many of them are doing this just to be able to drive everyday, because in some big cites of China , there are policies prohibiting cars on road for one weekday if they have certain last plate digit. (http://news.xinhuanet.com/english2010/china/2010-04/03/c_13236082.htm).

Comment: Asking around here, people tell me the sentence actually says nothing about whether or not the people already have a car, are replacing an old one or buying a second one and keeping their first car. It just says, as you say, 'buying a car for the second time'. The phrase '2 car family' is a common one, I suppose that's why I thought of it, but that does not follow from the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think this means 'purchasing the 2nd car of a family'.

The second hand cars are always translated as 二手车.